# Inline and Virtual

Tags: c++, virtual, inline

guys. I have read several threads about the interaction between inline and virtual co-existing in one function. In most cases, compilers won't consider it as inline. However, is the principle applied to the scenario when a non-virtual inline member function call a virtual function? say:

```
class ABC{
public:
    void callVirtual(){IAmVitrual();}
protected:
    virtual void IAmVirtual();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What principle? I would expect the compiler to generate a call to the virtual function. The call (in effect a jump-to-function-pointer) may be inlined but the `IAmVirtual` function is not.

The virtual function itself is not `inline`, and it is not called with qualification needed to inline it even if it were, so it can't be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of virtual functions is that the compiler generally doesn't know which of the derived class implementations will be needed at run-time, or even if extra derived classes will be dynamically loaded from shared libraries.  So, in general, it's impossible to inline.  The one case that the compiler *can inline* is when it happens to know for sure which type it's dealing with because it can see the concrete type in the code and soon afterwards - with no chance of the type having changed - see the call to the virtual function.  Even then, it's not *required* to try to optimise or inline, it's just the only case where it's even possible.

You shouldn't try to fight this unless the profiler's proven the virtual calls are killing you.  Then, first try to group a bunch of operations so one virtual call can do more work for you.  If virtual dispatch is still just too slow, consider maintaining some kind of discriminated union: it's a lot less flexible and cleanly extensible, but can avoid the virtual function call overheads and allow inlining.

All that assumes you really need dynamic dispatch: some programmers and systems over-use virtual functions just because OO was the in thing 20 years ago, or they've used an OO-only language like Java.  C++ has a rich selection of compile-time polymorphic mechanisms, including `template`s.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `callVirtual()` will be inlined. Any non-virtual function can be a good candidate of being `inline` (obviously last decision is upto compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual functions have to be looked up in the Virtual Method Table, and as a result the compiler cannot simply move them to be inline.  This is generally a runtime look up. An inline function however may call a virtual one and the compiler can put that call (the code to look up the call in the VMT) inline.